# how To Improve that ComplexPlot3D

Tags: plotting, complex

I have in mind the result of

```
ComplexPlot3D[Log[MittagLefflerE[1/2, z]],{z, -50 - 50*I, 50 + 50*I}, 
PlotPoints -> 300,PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

In particular, the plot should be seen over the whole quadrat.

Addition 1. Up to @J.M. is away sugestion,

```
ComplexPlot3D[Log[MittagLefflerE[1/2, z]], {z, -50 - 50*I, 50 + 50*I},
   PlotPoints -> 300, PlotRange -> All,   WorkingPrecision -> 25] // AbsoluteTiming
```

{874.714,[image] }

Addition 2. The command

```
ComplexPlot3D[MittagLefflerE[1/2, z], {z, -50 - 50*I, 50 + 50*I},PlotRange -> All]
```

performs an empty plot.

Addition 3. Following another suggestion by @J. M. will be back soon,

```
ComplexPlot3D[Log[MittagLefflerE[1/2, z]], {z, -50 - 50*I, 50 + 50*I},
 PlotPoints -> 300, PlotRange -> {0, 200}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

[image]

Comment: Some of it is due to large intermediate results not being computed accurately in machine precision; try setting `WorkingPrecision -> 25`, and there should be less holes in the surface.

Comment: @J. M. is away: Thank you for your useful suggestion.

Comment: You could try increasing the setting of both `WorkingPrecision` and `PlotPoints` further, but of course this will make your plots take longer to generate.

Comment: @J.M. will back soon: All that is not so simple. In particular, the argument of the function under consideration is not constant as the above plots show. Also the result of ComplexPlot3D[Log[MittagLefflerE[1/2, z]], {z, -50 - 50*I, 0 + 0*I}, 
 PlotPoints -> 300, PlotRange -> All] is not correct.

Comment: "the result ... is not correct" - even after adjusting `WorkingPrecision`?

Comment: @J.M. will be back soon: Yes, the result with WorkingPrecision->25 is not correct because it shows a constant arguments by the same colors in two domains. The domain in blue is shown somewhat better.

Comment: Rather than constant argument, that would be instead interpreted as the phase not varying very much in that region. Did you check typical values of `Arg[Log[MittagLefflerE[1/2, z]]]` in that region?

Comment: Can the options of ComlexPlot3D be applied to improve the plot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The branch cut structure here is very dense, which can be very hard for plotters to pick up.

Here are the cuts in a part of your domain:

```
Quiet @ Show[
  ComplexPlot[
    Log[MittagLefflerE[1/2, z]], {z, 0, 20 + 20 I}, 
    Exclusions -> None, ColorFunction -> {Automatic, None}, ImageSize -> Large
  ],
  ContourPlot[
    Im[E^(x + I y)^2 Erfc[-x - I y]] == 0, 
    {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}, 
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, f}, Re[E^(x + I y)^2 Erfc[-x - I y]] <= 0], 
    PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 1, ContourStyle -> Black
  ]
]
```

[image]

We can turn these off with `Exclusions -> None`:

```
ComplexPlot3D[
  Log[MittagLefflerE[1/2, z]], 
  {z, -50 - 50*I, 50 + 50*I},
  Exclusions -> None, 
  NormalsFunction -> None,
  PlotRange -> All, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 25
]
```

[image]